# What is the quickest way to check if an svn working copy has changes?

Tags: c#, powershell, svn, sharpsvn

I want to add information to assembly on build if the working copy is modified (with exception to from ignore-on-commit changeset), but I'm afraid checking all changes using SharpSVN might slow down the build in a 100MB working copy with 1000+ files. Hence - what is a quickest way to get *only* the information that there are uncommited and/or unstaged changes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just need the result: modified vs unmodified you could do something like this C# code:

```
// using SharpSvn;

bool foundModification = false;
using (SvnClient client = new SvnClient()
{
   client.Status(@"C:\my\working\copy",
                 delegate(object sender, SvnStatusEventArgs e)
                 {
                    foundModification = true;
                    e.Cancel = true;
                 });
}
```

This does +- the absolute minimum required to find if there are actual changes in your working copy and stops the moment it found the first result.

SubWCRev and svnversion use a similar approach, but do some additional checks inside wc.db (assuming Subversion 1.7 or newer).

You probably want to extend the delegate a bit to skip some kinds of changes. (The Changelist is available as a property on the SvnStatusEventArgs object)

Answer (score 3):

If you just need a "yes/no" as to whether there are local modification and you have [TortoiseSVN](http://tortoisesvn.net/) installed, you can use [SubWCRev](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/nightly/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-subwcrev.html):

> SubWCRev is Windows console program which can be used to read the status of a Subversion working copy and optionally perform keyword substitution in a template file.

But more to your requirements, if you invoke it like this:

```
subwcrev C:\your\wc\path -n
```

It just looks for changes in the working copy and returns an error code (it's 7 according to the docs) if any are found.  For example, from a Powershell prompt:

```
> subwcrev C:\your\wc\path -n
SubWCRev: 'C:\your\wc\path'
Working copy has local modifications!

> $LASTEXITCODE
7
```

Using this is probably easier than parsing the output of `svn status`.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't worked with SharpSVN. However, Subversion itself is fairly quick in detecting changes -- especially with versions 1.7 and newer. We have projects with 10,000 or more files, and Subversion takes mere seconds to find changes and list all of the files. NSvn (which is the name of the .NET Subversion library) should be fairly fast at doing this task. If not, try using the Subversion command line in PowerShell.

A curious question: Why is your working copy so big? Do you have all of the .NET third party libraries checked in there? If so, you should take a look at [NuGet](http://www.nuget.org). NuGet is .NET's answer to Maven. Maven is a dependency management system for Java.

Instead of adding third party Java libraries into your repository, you use Maven's `pom.xml` file to describe the dependencies you need. Maven then fetches these libraries from various Maven repositories around the world. The results are smaller source repositories that are easier to maintain. Smaller working copies, faster checkouts, and instead of mysterious third party libraries (where did this come from? What version is this?), you have a description of your dependencies (I'm using version 1.2 of this library that's from this project).

If you're not using NuGet, I suggest you take a look at it. It works with your current Microsoft project files, so you don't have to overhaul your current build system.

Comment: Ok, I'll check how fast can it work with svn status - I thought the status would take quite a lot of disk work which would be painful on builds. Working copy is quite big because It's a multi-project solution with MVC web application (and lots of resources, images and so on), code doesn't take that much in comparison to the resources. Yes, we're using NuGet for all the packages, thanks for the close look of the possible issue :)

Comment: Never heard of NSvn, do you have a link?  [SharpSvn](https://sharpsvn.open.collab.net/) has been the only (mature) .NET SVN bindings that I've seen.

Comment: NSvn was the old Subversion integration library of AnkhSVN. Since AnkhSVN 2.0 (read: about 6 years ago) this library was replaced by SharpSvn, and NSvn no longer updated.

Answer (score 0):

I think `svn status` is what you're looking for:

```
> svn status
M       auth\auth.c
M       auth\auth_spnego.c
```